# multiple variables on component emitter c#

Tags: c#, function, lambda

i started programming in c# yesterday. I'm coming from JS (almost webdevelopment).
I am stuck on a problem:
In Javascript I would write:

```
socket.on('step', function(data_x, data_y) {
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = data_x+","+data_y;
    console.log(data_x+", "+data_y);
});
```

But in C# I can't write:

```
socket.On(String.Format(rb), (data_x, data_y) =>
   {
      var tempValue_x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data_x);
      var tempValue_y = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data_y);
      UpdateData(String.Format("{0}, {1}", tempValue_x, tempValue_y));
   });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do more research before you post a question. I think in your case you have to learn about events in C#.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to define the function with parameter is a function or action in C#,
example:

```
public class SocketObject
{

}

public static class SocketExtension
{
    public static void On(this SocketObject socket, string name, Action<object, object> func)
    {
        // do something

        // call back
        func(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

now you can do this

```
var socket = new SocketObject();
socket.On("test", (param1, param2) =>
{

});
```

In c# you can use the function like the param (callback in js) by using Action and Func, learn more
[Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netcore-3.1)
and
[Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netcore-3.1)